# For an element that does not belong to a set, is the distance of it from any element in the set positive?

Tags: real-analysis

If $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and and $ x \notin D $,
Can I say that $ \forall y\in D \:\: \|x-y\|>0 ?$
Is there any counter-example to it if it is not the case?

Comment: Take another look at the properties that a norm must satisfy. One of them will do the job.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of $C$ in the question - don't you just want to say that $x$ is any point not in $D$?

Comment: Yeah you are right…I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the norm of a non-zero vector is strictly positive.

(of course, if a statement beginning with "for all" turns out not to be the case, then there are counterexamples to it)

Answer (score 0):

By **definition** $||x,y|| \ge 0$ and $||x,y|| = 0 \iff x=y$.

So if $y \in D$ and $x\not \in D$ then $x \ne y$ and so $||x,y|| \ge 0$ and $||x,y|| \ne 0$.  So.... $||x,y|| > 0$.

Yes.